# Add hover to Bokeh without losing rest of tools

Tags: python, bokeh

So with Bokeh I can do something like this to create a hover option:

```
From bokeh.models import HoverTool #add hover functionality
Hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[(name1:@column1), (name2:@columns2)])
Plot = figure(tools=[hover])
Plot.circle(x,y,hover_color=’red’)
```

However, by doing so, I lose the standard tools you get when you call figure() like pan, box_zoom, wheel_zoom, etc. I know I can add them back 1 by 1 inside the figure(tools=[]), but is there a way to only add hover to the rest of the default tools of figure(), after it is defined??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the add_tools() method, as outlined in the docs:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#specifying-tools

Slightly modified example from the docs:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

output_file("toolbar.html")

# create a new plot with the toolbar below
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
           title=None, toolbar_location="below")

p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 5, 8, 2, 7], size=10)

p.add_tools(HoverTool())

show(p)
```

Comment: No idea how I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: you can also append `hover` to the `p.tools` directly. internally it stores the tools in a list.